# How do I teleport armor stands to entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For one of my maps, I need to teleport an armor stand to a diamond. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @e selector to find the Armor Stand, for example`/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] x y z` This will work if you know exactly where the diamond will be, but if the position may vary, things get a bit more complicated. I don't think there's an easy way to get the NBT data from the diamond to differentiate it from other dropped items, so you would have to use the scoreboard tags to find the item (this requires using the 1.9 snapshots, there's a way for 1.8 too, but it's even more complicated):  
`/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item] add (tagname) {Item:{id:minecraft:diamond}}`
This will Mark all dropped diamonds with whatever name you put for tagname. From here, to teleport the diamond to the marked item you can use the command `/tp @e[type=ArmorStand] @e[tag=(tagname)]`

If you need to teleport a specific armor stand without affecting any others on the map, you can use the tag command again, except swapping the selector and tagname, as well as removing the NBT data from the end.